# How does one relate Boxes/Blocks to content types in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, block, content-type

Hi and thanks for any help given in advance. I'm looking to have boxes in drupal 7 to show up in a content type. Similar to Node References (https://drupal.org/project/references).

Can anyone point me to a module that may already exist or maybe if one does not exist, any advice on how to go about programming this feature?

Thanks again

Comment: I dont understand, do you want to display a block only in one content type?

Comment: well kind of ... I want to have a user create a node and be able to choose what blocks/boxes they want to show with that node. Very much like node references but with blocks/boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I went a slightly different route.

Here are my steps.

- I created a content type named "Sidebar Callouts"
- I then went to the "Basic Page" content type (replace basic page with your own content type)
- I added a field of field type "Entity Reference" with a widget of "Autocomplete"
- In the field settings I set "number of values" to unlimited
- While still in the field settings, I went to the Entity Selection area and I set mode to "simple" and selected the "Sidebar Callouts" content type that I created earlier

That's it. I now have a way to let the client choose a callout that is created as a node.

I wish I could have found a way to use Boxes but alas, project timelines did not allow me to look further into it.